# Прогресс бар долгого скрипта на ajax

Tags: php, javascript

Есть долгий скрипт на сервере который запускается через ajax, пытаюсь сделать для него прогрессбар. 
Скрипт на сервере запускается

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['process']=0;
session_write_close();
```

Что то там делает в процессе

```
foreach ($clear as $key => $array) {
$_SESSION['process'] = round(($key * 100 / $count)/2);
session_write_close();
//бла бла
}
```

Вторым запросом опрашиваю другой файл скрипта на сервере

```
session_start();
$array = array('process'=>$_SESSION['process']);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Но вот беда не работает так как хотелось бы, данные не обновляющийся, а если в цикле добавить session_start(); то обновляются где то раз 50 и потом ошибка валит

> net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186675/why-i-get-err-response-headers-too-big-on-chrome
header_remove ("Set-Cookie");

Читал на хабре в комментах писали что так не стоит делать, дабы вопросу не пропадать, как стоит делать?

Comment: Потому что сессия нужна для других целей, если вы в цикле стартуете и закрываете сессию, то формируется очень большый заголовки ответа, о чем говорит ошибка `net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наиболее простой вариант, который напрашивается исходя из вашей текущей архитектуры - писать % во временный файл, из него читать 2м скриптом, удалять его по окончании срипта.

Более красивое решение:

Страница с ajax:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var but = document.getElementById("but");
                but.onclick = doAjax;
            };

            function doAjax()
            {
                function prog(e)
                {
                    var text = request.responseText;
                    var field = document.getElementById("process");
                    field.innerHTML += "..." + Math.round(e.loaded/e.total*100) +'%';
                }


                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "/ajaxtest.php");
                request.send();
                request.onprogress = prog;
                request.onload = function ()
                {
                    var field = document.getElementById("process");
                    field.innerHTML += "...Загрузка завершена";
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="but" type="button">Запустить</button>
        <p id="process">Выполнено: 0%</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Серверный скрипт

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Length: 10000");

$parcel = str_repeat('.', 1000); // 1000 байт - 10%

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $tmp = time() + 0.1;
    while (time() < $tmp);
    echo $parcel;
    flush(); // выталкиваем буфер браузеру
    ob_flush(); // выталкиваем буфер браузеру
}
```

Идея: выдаем ответ по частям, сразу очищая буфер и передавая данные браузеру, а в ajax скрипте обрабатываем событие progress. В заголовке передаем количество байт, оно попадет в `e.total` в ajax скрипте. Отправляем ответ точками (байтами), а не числом, так как Chrome видимо сильнее буферизирует ответ и не возбудит событие `progress` в `XMLHttpRequest` пока не получит достаточное число байт (кстати оно даже больше 1000, так как начинает в Chrome с 20%, а в Mozille c 10%, в Mozille и числами можно).

Comment: будет конфликт чтения записи файла, лучше уж в БД тогда =)

Comment: @korolariya да возможно, это кривое решение. Написал вам более интересный вариант.

Comment: тогда уже еще надо `ob_start();` и `ob_end_flush();`

Answer (score 1):

Пишете статус в БД – это самое простое.
Или используйте [потоки](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.stream.php) и [вебсокеты](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/)

Comment: опишите подробнее, как можно использовать потоки для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Например запустить как демон php скрипт с созданием потока на порту stream_socket_server() и все остальные скрипты пишут в это соединение. Но надо не забыть про проверку кому какие данные принадлежат. Да да, знаю, это не очень хорошее решение, но имеет место быть, если например БД не используется или перегружена. А php демона можно контролировать с помощью [supervisor](http://supervisord.org)

Comment: + к этому вебсокеты можно заюзать. 1 запрос запускает долгий скрипт и потом через вебсокет получаем каждое изменение прогресса, который в свою очередь долгий скрипт пишет в поток

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать long-pooling:
1. Создавать запрос к php скрипту, который не закрывает соединение;
2. Отправлять ответ только при изменении статуса;
3. На стороне клиента после получения ответа создавать новый запрос.

[php-long-polling](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling) — вот пример технологии, возможно это overkill, но если отображение статуса так важно, то почему нет?

Comment: long-pooling отдает ответ 1 раз, это запрос который висит пока сервер не ответит, поэтому тут он для вызова первого скрипта не нужне

Comment: могут заминусовать=) потому как хостинги разные коряво настраивают сервера, я так уже hostinger.ru  положил причем вместе с их сайтом, и еще один друг вырубил, ему нужно было опрашивать периодически файл, я ему посоветовал long-polling его премии лишили, и сервак лег когда 20 000 человек зашли на страницу сервер повесил кучу таких запросов и походу памяти не хватило, потом появился у нас админ, крутой, он начальником какой то крупной конторы работал раньше, и он показал как разруливать такие висяки на сервере