# Нужен прогрес бар PHP

Tags: php

Делаю рассылку из базы, получаю 50 000 `id` и через

```
 foreach ($massiv as $odin) { }
```

делаю рассылку по базе.

Хочу прикрепить прогресс бар к этому. Как это сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Прогресс бар долгого скрипта на ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449797/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Рассылка у Вас на сервере, прогрессбар на клиенте. Соответственно Вам нужно передавать прогресс на клиента. Сделать это можно двумя способами:

1. Последовательные AJAX запросы на отправку очередной порции данных
2. Передача данных на клиента по мере рассылки через WebSocket

Второй способ более правильный и безопасный

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите все красиво, тогда тут потребуется AJAX.
**Суть вот в чем:**
Вы должны 50000 ид разделить допустим на 100 (получается 500) и с помощью AJAX делать запросы к скрипту и выполнять по 500 штук за одно подключение. В итоге, когда скрипт отработает он вернет на обработчик AJAX'a информацию о проделанной работе. В случае если все прошло успешно, мы выводим информацию. Вывести можно как `alert(), console.log(), document.write()....`

А можно еще в виде диаграммы используя тег `progress` или самим создать две дивки